# How to make ts. file keeping the right path after compiled to js file?

Tags: node.js, typescript

My folder structure

```
Node (root directory)
 -data
  -123.mp4
 -src
  -test.ts
 -build
  -test.js
```

My ts. file in src folder,

```
import { createReadStream, createWriteStream } from 'fs';
const readStram = createReadStream('../data/123.mp4')
const writeStream = createWriteStream('../data/copy.mp4')
```

compiled to build folder,

```
import { createReadStream, createWriteStream } from 'fs';
const readStram = createReadStream('../data/123.mp4');
const writeStream = createWriteStream('../data/copy.mp4');
```

I got an error, that said no such file or directory, what should I do to keep js file has the right path to load 123.mp4?

trying to use the path module, but there is another error mentioned __dirname can't use in ES module.

my ts.config

```
{
  "include": ["src/**"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "compilerOptions": {
  
    "target": "ES2016" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
    "module": "Node16" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "rootDir": "./src" /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */,
    "moduleResolution": "Node16" /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */,
    "outDir": "./build" /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

Comment: can't really help with everything but: with es modules you don't have access to __dirname. you can bring it back with: 
`import * as url from 'url';
    const __dirname = url.fileURLToPath(new URL('.', import.meta.url));`
[alternatives to __dirname](https://blog.logrocket.com/alternatives-dirname-node-js-es-modules/)

Comment: Can you post the error message? TS compiler shouldn't complain about static file path

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your assets to `file`

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#files